# SQL Query: get all fields that match a list of values(from subquery)

Tags: sql, join

I am struggling to think of a way to finish this query.   The goal is to get all of the fields (* is fine) stored for each ID, sorted by the session ID.

**LOGIC:**

innermost query: get all sessionID

inner query: get all ID's grouped by sessionID

outer query: get all fields for all IDs

I believe I need to put my current query inside of an where clause...

'' WHERE [ID] IN (*all IDs from subqueries*) ''

```
SELECT DISTINCT sess.[ID], sess.[KEY], sess.[VALUE]
FROM [database]as e

INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [ID], [KEY], [VALUE]
        FROM [database]
        WHERE[KEY] = 'SessionId'
    ) as sess
    ON e.[ID] = sess.[ID]
ORDER BY [VALUE] DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit hard to type on the mobile app, but this is the idea:

```
With s as (
           Sub query
          )
Select ...
From t join
     s
     On ...
Group by t.sessid
Having count(*) = (select count(*) from s)
```